# pip install dryscrape fails with "error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/webkit_server'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, installation, dryscrape

I need to install dryscrape for python but I got error, what's the problem?

```
C:\Users\parvij\Anaconda3\Scripts>pip install dryscrape
```

I got this:

```
Collecting dryscrape
Collecting webkit-server>=1.0 (from dryscrape)
  Using cached webkit-server-1.0.tar.gz
Collecting xvfbwrapper (from dryscrape)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in c:\users\parvij\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from dryscrape)
Building wheels for collected packages: webkit-server
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for webkit-server ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\parvij\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c"import setuptools,tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\parvij\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-o7nlv0dz\\webkit-server\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\parvij\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp71w59qv6pip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/webkit_server'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for webkit-server
  Running setup.py clean for webkit-server
Failed to build webkit-server
Installing collected packages: webkit-server, xvfbwrapper, dryscrape
  Running setup.py install for webkit-server ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\parvij\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c"import setuptools,tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\parvij\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-o7nlv0dz\\webkit-server\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open',open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\parvij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-tyzalid7-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/webkit_server'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\parvij\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\parvij\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-o7nlv0dz\\webkit-server\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\parvij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-tyzalid7-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\parvij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-o7nlv0dz\webkit-server\
```

my operating system is windows 8

my python version is 3.5

Comment: for mac 'brew install qt'

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Download webkit-server from github

```
git clone https://github.com/niklasb/webkit-server.git webkit-server
```

Change in webkit-server/setup.py :

```
shutil.copy('src/webkit_server', self.build_purelib)
shutil.copy('src/webkit_server', self.build_platlib)
```

to

```
shutil.copy('src/webkit_server.pro', self.build_purelib)
shutil.copy('src/webkit_server.pro', self.build_platlib)
```

then

```
cd webkit-server
python setup.py install
```

There you go.

Comment: THIS ANSWER WORKS I'VE BEEN LOOKING FOR SO LONG

Comment: It's crazy but it's true

Comment: I tried this and dryscrape compiled. However, when I called it from scrapy,  I got FileNotFoundError for webkit_server. I made a symlink from webkit_server.pro to webkit_server. That gave me a permissions error. I gave it execute permissions and then got "OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error" on webkit_server

Comment: You may have to run `python setup.py install` as sudo

Comment: @user3185563 so how did you solve that problem? I got stuck just where you'd been, and I'd like to know how you dealt with it.

Comment: You may have to run `python3 setup.py install` instead

Answer (score 3):

Need to install http://www.qt.io. Also, The 5.6+ version of Qt removes the Qt WebKit module in favor of the new module Qt WebEngine. So far, webkit-server has not been ported to WebEngine (and likely won't be in the near future), so Qt <= 5.5 is a requirement.

Answer (score -1):

From the [doc](http://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), you have to installed also [requirements](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape/blob/master/requirements.txt).
You can do this as follow

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

After this retry to install **dryscrape**.

Comment: but this command with that file has this error:
C:\Users\parvij\Anaconda3\Scripts>pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting git+git://github.com/niklasb/webkit-server.git (from -r requirements.
txt (line 2))
  Cloning git://github.com/niklasb/webkit-server.git to c:\users\parvij\appdata\local\temp\pip-5dfsvle5-build
  Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q git://github.com/niklasb/webkit-server.git C:\Users\parvij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-5dfsvle5-build
Cannot find command 'git'

Comment: You have to install also git or clone manually the project and remove the second requirements from txt file.

Comment: The error occurs during webkit-server installation which is one of the requirements, IMO requirements.txt is not explicitly required.

apt-get install qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev build-essential python-lxml python-pip xvfb

pip install dryscrape

These two are sufficient to install dryscrape.
The webkit-server problem seems to be an issue of its own.

Comment: This answer comes up with the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Need do install `qt4` and `libqtwebkit-dev` for compile `webkit-server`, then follow the steps of [@Erwan Clügairtz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42809856/11831316)

`sudo apt install libqtwebkit-dev qt4`