# The system cannot find the file specified with dryscrape

Tags: python, dryscrape

I am trying to use dryscrape like this:

```
    import dryscrape
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    session = dryscrape.Session()
    session.visit(my_url)
    response = session.body()
```

But I get the following error, Any way to resolve the following errors

```
> <module>
>     session = dryscrape.Session()   File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\dryscrape\session.py", line 22, in
> __init__
>     self.driver = driver or DefaultDriver()   File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\dryscrape\driver\webkit.py", line 30, in
> __init__
>     super(Driver, self).__init__(**kw)   File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\webkit_server.py", line 230, in __init__
>     self.conn = connection or ServerConnection()   File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\webkit_server.py", line 507, in __init__
>     self._sock = (server or get_default_server()).connect()   File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\webkit_server.py", line 450, in
> get_default_server
>     _default_server = Server()   File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\webkit_server.py", line 416, in __init__
>     stderr = subprocess.PIPE)   File "C:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
>     restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
>     startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Have you seen this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788816/pip-install-dryscrape-fails-with-error-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-s ?