# Python unable to pip install Dryscrape

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to install dryscrape python library using pip.

I tried :

```
pip install dryscrape
```

But i'm getting error, Traceback :

```
Collecting dryscrape
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/75/c45f796ec5bc7f98c38b9ae425390ef5f4a76153c8b5af946adb97e7e622/dryscrape-1.0.tar.gz
Collecting webkit_server>=1.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/f2/f4f454cccde75e95359e91fa58f14497350dc97e58534f9003c77eca3dff/webkit-server-1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from dryscrape) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: xvfbwrapper in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from dryscrape) (0.2.9)
Installing collected packages: webkit-server, dryscrape
    Running setup.py install for webkit-server ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dp/kmfkxb6s6138xklg8y951y140000gn/T/pip-install-ljjlzqoi/webkit-server/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dp/kmfkxb6s6138xklg8y951y140000gn/T/pip-install-ljjlzqoi/webkit-server/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/dp/kmfkxb6s6138xklg8y951y140000gn/T/pip-record-gmf2apev/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/dp/kmfkxb6s6138xklg8y951y140000gn/T/pip-install-ljjlzqoi/webkit-server/
    Complete output (4 lines):
    running install
    running build
    sh: qmake: command not found
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/webkit_server'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dp/kmfkxb6s6138xklg8y951y140000gn/T/pip-install-ljjlzqoi/webkit-server/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dp/kmfkxb6s6138xklg8y951y140000gn/T/pip-install-ljjlzqoi/webkit-server/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/dp/kmfkxb6s6138xklg8y951y140000gn/T/pip-record-gmf2apev/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install dryscrape fails with "error: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory: 'src/webkit\_server'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788816/pip-install-dryscrape-fails-with-error-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-s)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the issue, so I tried googling the following:

> Dryscrape no such file or directory found src/webkit_server

and the first result is [This StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788816/pip-install-dryscrape-fails-with-error-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-s). I followed the instructions there are it solved the issue.